# In Kibana can I visualize or extract images and video data from Hadoop (Hive) using Elastic search and Hadoop connector

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, kibana

While working with self driving car data, I have requirement like with given range of timestamp, I need to search Elastic Search and get the vehicle location image,video,latitudes,longitudes,speeds of vehicle. The input data will be loaded into Hadoop using Kafka+Spark Streaming, this transformed data contains json files, images, videos. The json file has attributes like course,speed,timestamp,latitude,longitude,accuracy. The json file name matches with corresponding image name and video name except extensions(.JPG, .JSON) differs. As the search should fetch results very fast on Petta bytes of data, we are asked to use Elastic search and Kibana here by integrating with Hadoop(Impala or presto may not match performance of kibana).
Problem here is we can store image and video data in Hadoop using sequence file format. But can the same data be indexed in ES with Hadoop integration? or can we fetch image or video data directly from hive to Kibana while searching? Or is there alternate way. Your help is much appreciated here.

Comment: Kibana doesn't have any native image or video viewer, AFAIK. And data doesn't go directly from Hive to Kibana, it still goes through Elastic

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understood there is no viewer but can I view at least metadata related to images and videos which again stored in Hive.

Comment: Probably, so where exactly are you stuck doing that? It's not clear if your issues are with Hadoop or Elasticsearch... Personally, I've never used Sequencefile or ES-Hadoop package, so I would just use Kafka Connect directly into Elastic and skip Hadoop and Spark completely, but I guess that depends on the data